# Django send_mail not working while smtplib works

Tags: python, django, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I have a setup where I am using "send_mail" to send emails to the users using a gmail account. For some reason this function returns "smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed".

I am using a gmail account with 2 factor security enabled and an app password.

If I just build a script using smtplib, it works. I am not sure how exactly to debug this issue.

---

Edit 1:
'send_mail' Seems to work if I remove "**connection_params" from being passed to "self.connection_class" on line 81 in 'django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py'

Edit 2:
Changing "smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-relay.gmail.com', 587)" to "smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-relay.gmail.com', 587, local_hostname='localhost')" results in the same error in case of smtplib

The problems seems to lie in the following:
value "localhost" is assigned to "connection_params" on line 69 in 'django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py' in the following manner (you may notice, there is no 'if' check, as the comment states):

```py
...
        # If local_hostname is not specified, socket.getfqdn() gets used.
        # For performance, we use the cached FQDN for local_hostname.
        connection_params = {"local_hostname": DNS_NAME.get_fqdn()}
...
```

The problem is, there is no way to assign 'local_hostname', as far as I can see, nor is there a way to set it to None

Edit 3:
It looks like Django is trying to do a 'socket.getfqdn()', which returns 'localhost', but 'localhost' is not fully qualified. Smtplib does the same 'socket.getfqdn()', but check for localhost and sets it to '127.0.0.1' instead.

This seems like a bug, with no way to set the 'local_hostname' value, and automatically setting it to 'localhost' which is not fully qualified.

---

Code snippets below:

settings.py

```py
...
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "myemail@costumgmail.com" 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypass" 
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
...
```

djangotest.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Django mail', 'This e-mail was sent with Django.', "myemail@costumgmail.com" , ['some.other@mail.com'], fail_silently=False)
# smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

smtplibtest.py

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

email_sender = "myemail@costumgmail.com" 
email_password="mypass"
email_reciever ='some.other@mail.com'

subject = "test"
body = "test"
em = EmailMessage()
em['sender'] = email_sender
em['to'] = email_reciever
em['subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body)

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-relay.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo() # (250, b'smtp-relay.gmail.com at your service, [188.26.233.149]\nSIZE 157286400\n8BITMIME\nSTARTTLS\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nPIPELINING\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8')

smtpObj.starttls() # (220, b'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS')

smtpObj.login(email_sender, email_password) # (235, b'2.7.0 Accepted')

smtpObj.sendmail(email_sender, email_reciever, em.as_string()) # OK
```

traceback from django:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 87, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 87, in open
    self.connection.starttls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 769, in starttls
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 612, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    (code, resp) = self.helo()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 441, in helo
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 405, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Comment: As far as I know - gmail has stopped external access since May 2022.

Comment: That's what Gmail does. Their anti-abuse measures make it unreliable as an outgoing mail service. Use any other.

Comment: 2 Factor Auth, with app password seems to still work. Also, this is reproducible, as I can use the smtplib script to send emails consistently, while django does not work